# Select an area on bitmap with 4 points using Matrix.setPolyToPoly

Tags: android, matrix, bitmap, transformation

I am playing with bitmap on Android and I am facing an issue when selecting an area on the bitmap using the 4 points. Not all the sets of 4 points work for me. In some cases, the result is just a blank bitmap instead of the cropped bitmap (like in the picture) and there is not any error in logcat(even memory error).
Here is the basic code I used to do the transformation.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class CropImageActivity extends Activity {
private ImageView mCroppedImageView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.crop);
    setupViews();
    doCropping();
}

private void doCropping() {
    Bitmap srcBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.sample);

    //target size
    int bitmapWidth = 400;
    int bitmapHeight = 400;

    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmapWidth, bitmapHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);

    //This is one of bad quadangle.
    points[0] = 0;    //top-left.x
    points[1] = 0;    //top-left.y
    points[2] = 230;  //top-right.x
    points[3] = 100;  //top-right.y
    points[4] = 350;  //bottom-right.x
    points[5] = 350;  //bottom-right.y
    points[6] = 0;    //bottom-left.x
    points[7] = 350;  //bottom-left.y

    float[] src = new float[]{
            points[0], points[1],
            points[2], points[3],
            points[4], points[5],
            points[6], points[7]
    };
    float[] dsc = new float[]{
            0, 0,
            bitmapWidth, 0,
            bitmapWidth, bitmapHeight,
            0, bitmapHeight
    };

    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    boolean transformResult = matrix.setPolyToPoly(src, 0, dsc, 0, 4);

    canvas.drawBitmap(srcBitmap, matrix, null);
    mCroppedImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
}

private void setupViews() {
    mCroppedImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.croppedImageView);
}
}
```

So, does the 4 points coordinates affect the canvas drawing or the matrix transformation? Any help is appreciated.

Thank you

[image]
[image: This works]

Comment: what is `boolean result` ?

Comment: The 'result boolean' variable is just  for logging purpose. I want to make sure that the command 'matrix.setPolyToPoly' works correctly.

Comment: `'''In some cases, the result is just a blank bitmap'''` in those cases what is `boolean result`?

Comment: Its value is 'true' for all the cases I tested. I do not know whether the matrix fails on calculation, but it does not throw any error :(

Comment: first of all make sure the matrix is correct, try calling `Canvas#concat` and then `Canvas#drawRect`

Comment: Hi pskink. You may be right. I tried to do `Canvas#concat` then `drawRect` and I could not see the Rectangle in some cases. So what is wrong with `matrix.setPolyToPoly` and how do I fix that?

Comment: Hi pskink, the code is basically what I have posted.

Comment: just wanted to run & test it but in that case it is too much work...

Comment: @pskink I just add the full code of the main activity, you just need a layout with an image view and a sample picture to run it. I cannot figure out why the set of points (in code) does not work as expected. Thanks Pskink.

Comment: it seems that `setPolyToPoly` is not a "panacea" in your case, i think you should try: `Canvas#drawBitmapMesh` or `Canvas#drawVertices`

Comment: Thanks @pskink for your suggestion. I have just taken a look at the `drawBitmapMesh` api, but I do not know how to apply it to crop and distort the quadangle to a rectangle bitmap. Anyway, I will try it.

Comment: Finally, I solve my issue using OpenGL. Thanks for the answer in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17648499/how-to-capture-an-image-in-android-with-coordinates)!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I solve my issue using OpenCV. Thanks for the answer in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17648499/how-to-capture-an-image-in-android-with-coordinates)! It seems that `Matrix.setPolyToPoly` does not work for all the cases.

Answer (score 0):

Everything is much simpler..

```
     @Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();

    matrix.setPolyToPoly(src, 0, dst, 0, 4);
    canvas.setMatrix(matrix);
    canvas.drawBitmap(bit,0,0,null );
}
```

Comment: Please add some details and/or info about your code. So the OP, and maybe new users can easily understand your answer.

Comment: The above supplemented the answer. I get Bitmap and arrays in which the distortion points are described. Sorry for the machine translation.

Answer (score 0):

The bug you see is not in `Matrix.setPolyToPloy` but in CPU rasterization. To workaround it, you can simply creating a new transformed `Bitmap` without using a `Canvas`, then crop the `Bitmap` to get desired result.