# I would like to capture an image between four coordinates, as below

Tags: android

I convert the image into bitmap and then set it as background to a relative layout. And I know these four coordinates.

Then how could I get the image inside the box and set it to another layout as background?

Comment: could you explain you purpose in more details ?

Comment: i have one polygonview that can generate dynamic squre and that cordinates points i will try to attach to image from our gallery please tell me ans.

Comment: that is problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17648499/how-to-capture-an-image-in-android-with-coordinates